# I am new to node js, am trying to implement "Account Signin" in Dialogflow But, I am getting this error "The agent returned an empty TTS"

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

```
const app = dialogflow({
  clientId: MY_CLIENT_ID,
});

app.intent('Start Signin', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
});


app.intent('Get Signin', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
    conv.ask(`I got your account details, ${payload.name}. What do you want to do next?`);
  } else {
    conv.ask(`I won't be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?`);
  }
});
```

Above is the code,
Also, I did create the intents as the name in the intents tab and fulfillment tab. I did enable the account link for the project with which I am working with and am using only google-sign and got client id. And created an event `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` in 'Get Signin' intent but still facing the same problem

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your setup for your ```Get Signin``` intent in Dialogflow? This would give us some more information about your setup

Comment: Yeah sure @Jordi, also I have enabled the fulfillment for that intent, [link]https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1SfIrF4ddNtL4HxDH3E-Oqfa_-EC-9MK0

Comment: Do you run into the error before or after the account linking prompt?

Comment: before the prompt@NickFelker

Comment: Can you provide a sample conversation about what you're trying, what oyu're getting back, and at what point in the conversation the error is triggered? Seeing the screen shots for the "Start Signin" intent may also help. Have you tested this in the simulator? If so, screen shots from there could also be useful. Are there any errors generatedw hen the "Get Signin" Intent is triggered/ In short, if you can update your question with as much information as possible, the better our chances are of being able to guide you.

Comment: @Prisoner I got it working by changes version in package.json file, also what if I want to access the "signin", eg. to get conv, : `let conv = agent.conv();` but what to write for signin?

Comment: I don't understand your (new) question. You may want to create an answer explaining what you did, to help others with the same problem, and create a new question with as many details as possible about what your new issue is.

Comment: @Prisoner oh okay and thanks